# restored old database now some characters have changed?

Tags: encoding

I had some site issues so I had to restore DB from old backup
I used phpmy admin.... import function to restore DB

Now all of sudden some characters have changed to "? "
I have noticed mostly apostrophes changing to question marks.

Like here
http://www.wedmepretty.com/ombre-inspired-wedding-and-event-designs/

Any idea how to fix it?

I have tried the comment out part

```
    They should look like the following after you comment them out:

    //define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
    //define('DB_COLLATE', '');
```

But it has not been fixed...
Please Help

Comment: What method did you use to backup and restore your database?  Was it a plugin, or phpmyadmin, or... ?

Comment: @joetek php my admin.... import function

Comment: @David-Lee can you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok! seems to have it fixed only by
  choosing Character set of the file  latin1
while importing backed up database

something mentioned by @chris-o

here
[Faulty restore of the database, encoding issue](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/12607/faulty-restore-of-the-database-encoding-issue?rq=1)